# Grammar of "good on"

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

Here is the sentence: "We go to the cinema every now and then, but only if there's something good **on**"

My question is: I don't know why the author had to put the word "on" after "good". What is the purpose behind this?

Can someone please help me answer this question.

Thanks.

Comment: The rest of the sentence is elided.  Read it as "something good on the screen".

Comment: I'll note that this wording is most idiomatic when used to refer to TV -- "There's nothing good on!"

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, the "on" refers to "on whatever media". I would usually associate "good on" more with television and "good playing" with cinema.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!